# Boost.Spirit: Why does phrase_parse behave differently to parse when parsing eol?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Why does `qi::phrase_parse` return `false` for `qi::eol`? I expect it to return `true` as `qi::parse` does.

```
using namespace boost::spirit;

const std::string s = "\n";

auto it = s.begin();
bool match = qi::phrase_parse(it, s.end(), qi::eol, ascii::space);    
std::cout << std::boolalpha << match << '\n';

it = s.begin();
match = qi::parse(it, s.end(), qi::eol);    
std::cout << std::boolalpha << match << '\n';
```

Result:

```
false
true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The skipper skips whitespace.

Whitespace includes `eol`.

Therefore, `eol` is never matched.

*TIP*: Use `blank` for whitespace *other than* `eol`